# Vertical placement of Fontawesome icons

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

I am trying to align vertical blocks containing icons and some text. Everything works as expected until the text is too large for the block.

```css
.big-icons .big-icon {
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.2em;
}
.big-icons .big-icon a .text {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.big-icons .big-icon a {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="big-icons">

  <span class="big-icon">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-magic fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        <span class="text">Short title</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="visible-xs divider"></div>

  <span class="big-icon">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-area-chart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        <span class="text">Very long long text</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="visible-xs divider"></div>

  <span class="big-icon">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-dropbox fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        <span class="text">Title</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="visible-xs divider"></div>

</div>
```

How do i make the link containing text "Very long long text" to not intersect with text "Title" on the right ?

Comment: You want to add the text into the icon ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the fa-stack-1x class gives the icon `position:absolute` and thats why its not being centered properly. I would try to use fa just to render the icon in certain size and do everything else in my own css. The circle with border radius, own position etc.